# Asterisk Voip Error : Chan_alsa.so file missing

Tags: asterisk, voip, core-audio

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and was setting up asterisk 15.3.0.I am following a beginners guide from here[Set up Asterisk](https://mike42.me/blog/2015-01-02-how-to-set-up-asterisk-in-10-minutes)

Asterisk and linphone  4.1 were installed successfully.My Users.conf file looks like this:

```
[6001]
fullname = Example Bob
secret = 1234
hassip = yes
context = users
host = 192.168.0.129


[6002]
fullname = Example Joe
secret = 1234
hassip = yes
context = users
host = dynamic
```

and Extensions.conf file:

```
[users]
exten => 6001,1,Dial(SIP/6001)
exten => 6002,1,Dial(SIP/6002)
```

When I hit 'sip show peers' on the Asterisk CLI, I get both the users, However when I type 'console dial 6001', it gives me an error saying chan_oss.co is not found.After Searching for sometime, I found out that I am supposed to load chan_alsa.so. But when I try to load 'chan_alsa.so' , I get an error saying:

```
module 'chan_alsa.so': /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/chan_alsa.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can't find any solution for this , in the directory there is no file called chan_alsa.so

Answer (score 0):

Reason: you have no module chan_alsa.so in your asterisk lib directory(see /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf

Possible causes:

1. When you do compilation from source was no alsa-dev or alsa-libs
2. When you installed via package manager you not installed asterisk-alsa package.

Comment: So How do I add it?